# How can I disable deletion of admin in Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, datatable

```
function deleteData(id){
   
    var csrf_token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    swal({
        title: 'Confoirm to delete?',
        text: "Irreversible process!",
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        confirmButtonText: 'Confirm!',
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
    }).then(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url : "{{ url('admins') }}" + '/' + id,
            type : "POST",
            data : {'_method' : 'DELETE', '_token' : csrf_token},
            success : function(data) {
                table.ajax.reload();
                swal({
                    title: 'Successful delete',
                    text: data.message,
                    type: 'success',
                    timer: '1500'
                })
            },
            error : function () {
                swal({
                    title: 'Oops...',
                    text: data.message,
                    type: 'error',
                    timer: '1500'
                })
            }
        });
    });
}
```

```
public function apiAdmins()
{
    $admin = User::all();

    return Datatables::of($admin)
        ->addColumn('action', function($admin){
            return
                '<a onclick="deleteData('. $admin->id .')" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete </a>';

        })
        ->rawColumns(['action'])->make(true);
}
```

May I know how can I check the authorized user id like is it match with the admin to be deleted id while trying to perform delete? This is to avoid deleting all available admins until it becomes 0 and also to avoid deletion of the admin who is logging in (himself/herself). Thank you.

Comment: _When_ do you want to block this action? You can code something on the Front-end, i.e. during the `deleteData()` function, to check if `id` matches the currently authenticated User's `id`. Or you can handle this on the back-end, i.e. in the `apiAdmins()` function, by adding an `if()` statement to your `addColumn()` to not return the `<a>` element if the `$admin` is the same as the currently authenticated User. Or you can do this at the database layer; if the `id` being deleted is the same as the `id` of the "actor" performing the delete. Lots of options, give one a try and see what works.

Comment: thanks for your comment and suggestion. By the way, how can I improve the current codes to achieve the results that I want? is there any way? thanks!

Comment: Uh... My comment suggested ways to handle this in your current code... I don't know how you'd get the `id` of the current User in your front-end code or your database, but in your back-end code, just check `if ($admin === auth()->user()) { return null; }` (or similar), so the `<a>` element is not rendered.

Comment: haha i see..thanks very much Tim! I will try on your suggestion